# Apache Camel: Producer template does not add to SEDA endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I am not sure what the problem is with my small application, if it resides on the `RouteBuilder` or within the `ProducerTemplate`

Either way, my `"Test message"` is not logged when running this application.

What may be going wrong here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("seda:myqueue").log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${in.body").end();
            }
        });



        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = main.getOrCreateCamelContext().createProducerTemplate();
        producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("seda:myqueue");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("Test message");
    }
```

Comment: Could be because you missed to close the body with a curly braces ${in.body ? Or it is just a type when you pasted it here ?

Comment: No it's just a typo I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are creating and starting the context which is probably why the message never reaches your route. Here is an example to get you started:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-camel/apache-camel-hello-world-example/

```
import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CamelHelloWorldExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addComponent("activemq", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"));
            context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("activemq:queue:test.queue")
                    .to("stream:out");
                }
            });
            ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
            context.start();
            template.sendBody("activemq:test.queue", "Hello World");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } finally {
            context.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice context.start() and context.stop();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize that Main.addRouteBuilder does not associate this route with a CamelContext. And that everytime you call getOrCreateCamelContext() it creates a new one! Do you know what is the difference between Main.addRouteBuilder and CamelContext.addRoutes?

Comment: @DJ180, addRoutes adds existing routes that you defined in a RouteBuilder class. addRouteBuilder creates a route on the fly for you. Usually you create  your routes in a RouteBuilder class and then added to your context. You can do that in pure java or if you deploy to a Karaf environment use blueprint to declare and add them to the context.